# Browse button in android activity

Tags: android, file-browser

Currently I'm developing an application which requires a browse button in my activity. When I press the browse button I should be able to browse and select only text files my phone and sd card. Upon select the text file, the directory of the selected file should be displayed in a text view. Also, the content of the of the text file should be displayed in another text view. How to do this? Can someone please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To get the internal SD card you can use

```
String extStore = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
File f_exts = new File(extStore);
```

To get the external SD card you can use

```
String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
File f_secs = new File(secStore);
```

Running the code

```
 extStore = "/storage/emulated/legacy"
 secStore = "/storage/extSdCarcd"
```